# How to get data by count and category

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table like below

```
Person   |   Category    | Fav Colors
-----    | -----------   | ------
 one     |   Native      |  RED
 one     |   Native      |  GREEN
 two     |   Non-Native  |  RED
 two     |   Non-Native  |  BLUE
 three   |   Native      |  RED
 three   |   Native      |  GREEN
```

How can I get data by the number of people in each category for each color?

i.e.

```
Fav Color | Native  | Non-Native
--------- | --------| --------
RED       | 2       | 1
GREEN     | 2       | 0
BLUE      | 0       | 1
```

Comment: Could you end up having other categories besides 'Native' and 'Non-Native'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
select   `Fav Colors` as `Fav Color`,
         count(case category when 'Native' then 1 end) Native,
         count(case category when 'Non-Native' then 1 end) `Non-Native`
from     tbl
group by `Fav Colors`
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0f723/1)

NB: you did not mention any requirement for sort order. In case you need one, you could just list the column number(s) in the `order by` clause:

```
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: You want SUM and not COUNT

Comment: Did you try it, @DavidP? `sum` *also* works, but then you need to add the `else` clause. Not so with `count`.

Comment: COUNT (At least in Oracle) produces the wrong results. It counts it whether its 1 or not. I assume the same is true in MySQL, but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: `count` works, but what if I want to order the counts by the category. So highest come first.

Comment: @David P: You are wrong. `COUNT(expression)` counts the non-null values. `case category when 'Native' then 1 end` is 1 when true and null when false. So `COUNT` works perfectly.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a pivot

Comment: @Omnipresent: you want to sort by what?

Comment: You are correct. I am wrong. What doesn't work is COUNT(CASE exp WHEN x='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) which gave me the wrong results. Still think SUM is cleaner but it doesn't matter really.

Comment: Thorsten - I think he is looking for dynamic column names.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sort by the number of the count for the `Native` category. In the example in the question, `RED 2 ` would come before `BLUE 0`

Comment: @trincot How can the results be sorted by the count?

Comment: `order by count(case category when 'Native' then 1 end) desc` or simply `order by 2 desc`.

Comment: ah, nvmd. Order by works `order by count(case category when 'Native' then 1 end)`

Comment: Just updated my answer with the sort order consideration: use column number for shorter syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in Oracle, and so had to slightly rename the columns, but here is the idea:

```
select FAV_COLORS,SUM(CASE CATEGORY WHEN 'NATIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NATIVE,SUM(CASE CATEGORY WHEN 'NON-NATIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NON_NATIVE
from TEMP
GROUP BY FAV_COLORS
```